# Input Voltage in regulator output pin

Tags: voltage-regulator

If i input 5V on a regulator's output (the regulator is also 5V output rated), while the regulator has no voltage on its input, will it be damaged? The regulator i am using is L78. I could not find the answer/similar references on its [datasheet](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/41/4f/b3/b0/12/d4/47/88/CD00000444.pdf/files/CD00000444.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000444.pdf), this means there is no issue if i input up to 5V on its output, right?

[image]

I made an example diagram above. I guess this wont destroy my regulator, right?

Comment: First of all..... **Why** do you want to try and input 5V to the output? What is the point in doing this just to see if it would be damaged? By the way, the datasheet you linked has a block diagram *and* schematic diagram of the IC in it.

Comment: Well i made a pcb, where this regulator powers up my circuit (takes in 15V, outputs 5V). But this circuit, also connects to a computer via usb (FTDI and UART more specifically) and i have used a diode to let the current flow only from the computer to the pcb. When you connect the computer, the computer can also power the pcb, (with a small Vdrom from the regulator, 4.8V reach the pcb), and these 4.8V also go to the regulator's output. If, in any case the regulator is not powered, i would like to know the damage it can cause.
I got my answer from the users below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be aware that other (non ST) devices do have warnings about reverse powering 7805 regulators. Such as this from TI: -

[image]

The above talks about protecting the device in the case of the output voltage being taken greater than 7 volts so, if you were using the above device you would be OK feeding the output with 5 volts but, this may not be the case for the ST device because the word "reverse" is not mentioned in the data sheet as far as I can tell. This makes me doubt that the ST device is capable of sustained reverse operation.

It's safer all round to use a reverse diode as shown (in my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

You need to protect the regulator from this possibility; it can cause damage. See Figure 28 in your linked datasheet. Basically, you need a diode from output back to input, with the anode at the output terminal.